# UICollectionView cell: is it safe to bring cell.selectedBackgroundView to front?

Tags: ios, cell, subview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am just starting to implement a multiselect UICollectionView. Would the below be considered "safe" code (since i assume theres some reason it is called BackgroundView instead of AccessoryView or such) ? I had the idea to save some effort, i intend to keep track of the selected items at the indexpath for further use via an array.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 //....

 cell.selectedBackgroundView = someView_With_A_Checkmark_Image;
 [cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.selectedBackgroundView];

 //...
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe?? Ya of course it wont cause any error. If your backgroundView is above the contentView of the cell, then what is the significance of `contentView`??.

**Collection view cell structure**
[image]

If you select an item in the collection view, collectionView will switch the `BackgroundView` and `Selected background view`. So what you can do is give valid views as background view and selected background view upon configuring your custom cell or change any properties of the cell in **didSelectItem** to differentiate selection. That is better.

Then one more no need to keep track of selection using a separate array. **[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]** will give you selected items path at any point of time

Comment: Sounds good. It makes sense for me in a specific situation i guess instead of adding to content view, was just curious as it felt odd.